# yeoman angular generator finishes but empty directory

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular, yo

So I installed all deps and and have been trying to use `yo angular`, and everything seems to complete alright, except that the resulting directory is empty after everything finishes.

Thoughts as to why?

```
leonsas at leonsas in ~/testdataops> yo angular dataops

     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

Out of the box I include Bootstrap and some AngularJS recommended modules.

? Would you like to use Gulp (experimental) instead of Grunt? No
? Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? Yes
? Would you like to include Bootstrap? Yes
? Would you like to use the Sass version of Bootstrap? Yes
? Which modules would you like to include? angular-animate.js, angular-cookies.js, angular-resource.js, angular-route.js, angular-sanitize.js, angular-touch.js
 conflict app/styles/main.scss
? Overwrite app/styles/main.scss? overwrite
    force app/styles/main.scss
 conflict app/index.html
? Overwrite app/index.html? overwrite
    force app/index.html
identical bower.json
identical .bowerrc
 conflict package.json
? Overwrite package.json? overwrite
    force package.json
identical Gruntfile.js
identical README.md
   invoke   angular:common:/Users/leonsas/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
identical     .editorconfig
identical     .gitattributes
identical     .jscsrc
identical     .jshintrc
 conflict     .yo-rc.json
? Overwrite .yo-rc.json? overwrite
    force     .yo-rc.json
identical     .gitignore
identical     test/.jshintrc
identical     app/404.html
identical     app/favicon.ico
identical     app/robots.txt
identical     app/views/main.html
identical     app/images/yeoman.png
   invoke   angular:main:/Users/leonsas/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
 conflict     app/scripts/app.js
? Overwrite app/scripts/app.js? overwrite
    force     app/scripts/app.js
   invoke   angular:controller:/Users/leonsas/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
 conflict     app/scripts/controllers/main.js
? Overwrite app/scripts/controllers/main.js? overwrite
    force     app/scripts/controllers/main.js
 conflict     test/spec/controllers/main.js
? Overwrite test/spec/controllers/main.js? overwrite
    force     test/spec/controllers/main.js


Just found a `.yo-rc.json` in a parent directory.
Setting the project root at: /Users/leonsas
   invoke   karma:app


I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


   invoke       angular:route
   invoke           angular:controller:/Users/leonsas/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
 conflict             app/scripts/controllers/about.js
? Overwrite app/scripts/controllers/about.js? overwrite
    force             app/scripts/controllers/about.js
 conflict             test/spec/controllers/about.js
? Overwrite test/spec/controllers/about.js? (Ynaxdh)  conflict             test/karma.conf.js
▌ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
? Overwrite test/spec/controllers/about.js? overwrite
    force             test/spec/controllers/about.js
? Overwrite test/karma.conf.js? overwrite
    force             test/karma.conf.js
 conflict             package.json
? Overwrite package.json? (Ynaxdh)    invoke           angular:view:/Users/leonsas/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
? Overwrite package.json? overwrite
    force     package.json(Ynaxdh)
▌ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
dataops@ /Users/leonsas
└── angular-bootstrap-starter@1.0.1  extraneous

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2016-02-24 02:18:38 UTC)
loading tasks          168ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 48%
loading grunt-wiredep    8ms  ▇▇▇▇ 2%
wiredep:app            143ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 41%
wiredep:test            11ms  ▇▇▇▇▇ 3%
wiredep:sass            20ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 6%
Total 351ms
dataops@ /Users/leonsas
└── angular-bootstrap-starter@1.0.1  extraneous
leonsas at leonsas in ~/testdataops> ls
leonsas at leonsas in ~/testdataops> node -v
v5.6.0
leonsas at leonsas in ~/testdataops> npm -v
3.7.3
```

Comment: I think you look in the wrong directory. The script itself says you overwriting stuff. 'Overwrite app/scripts/controllers/main.js? overwrite'

Comment: It looks like it is writing into your home directory (/Users/leonsas), can you check and see if that is, in fact, the case?

Comment: Seems like that's right. Why is that the case if I'm in another dir? I thought yo would generate in the cwd.